# Segmentation fault with fgets()

Tags: c

The following code gives me a segmentation fault. I also tried using `malloc` for allocating `str`. I cannot avoid the segmentation fault. Please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int fd = open("/home/pdave/hello2.c", O_RDONLY);
    FILE* stream;
    stream = fopen("./home/pdave/hello2.c", "r");
    char lin[128];
    int ret = 0;
    int cnt = 0;
    char str[128];
    while((fgets(str, 128, stream)) != NULL) {
        printf("%d\t%d\t%s", cnt, ret, str);    
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not checking the return value of `fopen`. Use your debugger.

Comment: Check the return value of open and fopen? `/home/pdave/hello2.c` is not the same file path as `./home/pdave/hello2.c`...

Comment: probably return of fopen is `NULL`. Are you sure about `./home/pdave/hello2.c` location ?

Answer (score 3):

you can open your file only with `fopen()` so remove the first open of file:

```
int fd = open("/home/pdave/hello2.c", O_RDONLY);
```

And the file path in your `fopen()` function seems to be wrong:

```
stream = fopen("/home/pdave/hello2.c","r");
```

Comment: @user_of_ubuntu_linux: Indent for spaces, or select all and press Ctrl+K

Comment: @user_of_ubuntu_linux: just put your code and then select it and then click on the `{}` button in the top

Comment: @user_of_ubuntu_linux Indent *four* spaces, that is. With blank lines before and after the first and last lines of code, too.

Answer (score 1):

Return value of `fopen` will be NULL when file path wrong.

Using NULL to `fgets` leads to `SO`.

Your file path looks like wrong, Usually there will not any path like `./home/path`.

compare the return value of `fopen` with `NULL`, after `fopen`.

Try with:

```
stream = fopen("/home/pdave/hello2.c", "r");
if (stream == NULL) {
    printf("Error opening file\n");
    return -1;
}
```

Further [man fopen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) and [man fgets](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)